# SQL Server: convenient way to join many tables with same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have many tables, such as Customer-Age, Customer-Street,..., Customer-OtherField. I want to get them easily to one table, such that Customer-Age-Street-... - OtherField. I have currently used:

```
SELECT a.Customer, a.Age, b.Street,..., x.OtherField
FROM table1 a, table2 b,..., tableX x
WHERE a.Customer=b.Customer =c.Customer=d.Customer =... =x.Customer`.
```

I want to get simpler, more convenient way to join the tables with common identifier, `Customer`.

How to join conveniently many tables with common identifier in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: There is none. You should actually do your joins even more explicit with `join ... on ...` And having age and such in different tables - I don't see the point but that may be because of the vague example

Comment: this might be obvious, but if you dont want to write all joins, you can use the create view UI and select tables and it should auto generate the query based on table selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're doing it now is the most "convenient", but it's not optimal and can cause you headaches down the road. Too easy to accidentally do a cross join and it clutters up your `WHERE` clause with a bunch of unnecessary conditions.

A better choice is to use the `JOIN ON` syntax:

```
SELECT a.Customer, a.Age,b.Street,...,x.OtherField
FROM 
table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.Customer = b.Customer
INNER JOIN table3 c ON b.Customer = c.Customer
INNER JOIN tableX x on c.Customer = x.Customer
```

This cleans up your code and makes it easier to tell what you are joining on, rather than having to figure out which `WHERE` clause statements are being used to join tables and which are restricting the query results. It's not any more annoying to type either, you're just putting all those letters in a different place.

Comment: Note that you don't always need to use table aliases (`a, b, x` in your example). I think their original names should always be used unless there's a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @Dai Good point. Force of habit, in our internal coding standards we have to use the fully qualified name of the table every time unless we alias it. So you alias to protect your wrists and your sanity. :)

Comment: Why on earth is that a policy? A DBMS is smart enough to bind names correctly, even if it isn't fully-qualified (assuming you mean `{schemaName}.{tableName}`) - you only need to specify the schema name if you're intentionally making a cross-schema reference. I understand there's a cargo-cult that believes query compilation is faster with schema-qualified names, but I haven't seen benchmarks to support that notion. And I hope you never have to specify them using `{databaseName}.{schemaName}.{tableName}` - that's just bad.

Comment: There is no plugin or any thing to generate the association automatically by the same field names?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t.Customerid, t1.Age,t1.Street,t2.number
         FROM table AS  t
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t.Customer = t1.Customer
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer

This is basically the neat way to do it I would say. Aliases are very important as they are often used to make column names more readable, plus they avoid any confusions if you have multiple tables.